# DIV inside another DIV Not Loading Images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, expand

I am trying to create a drop down menu. The smaller DIV inside the main DIV that contains an image gallery does not load properly when the website is live (space is there but images do not show up). I am looking for the proper code to make this work properly. This is the code I am using for the drop down of the main DIV with the smaller image gallery DIVs inside.

Read More

The smaller DIVs with the image galleries work fine when the website is live until I change the beginning of the code to . I would like to get the drop down to start off closed and not open when the page is visited.

Comment: Please post all relevant code...

Comment: Not sure why the code did not post. The code for the "Read More" of the overall DIV is: <details open=""><summary><span style="background-color: #bfbfbf;"><div style="text-align: left;"><small>Read More</small><br></div></span></summary><div style="text-align: left;"><br>

Comment: When I change the beginning to <details close="'> the DIVs inside the main DIVs containing images do not load the images only the empty space

Comment: The code for the DIVs with the images is: <div class="image-gallery" gid="1">
{image 3}
{image 4}
</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>

Comment: Can you please edit your post and include a code block? simply paste your markup in inside your post and click the '{}' button to format the markup as a code block.

Answer (score 0):

I am going blind here, but I am assuming that your div does not have height. Give height property to a div and that should solve the problem. Its a common mistake.

Please leave us some code sample next time. Ty.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see your code yet, but here is some possible help.
With showing or hiding HTML elements, like div's, you are dealing with visibility and display. One hides the element altogether and the other takes up the space but does not display the inner elements.

You can read more about display and visibility here:

https://www.lifewire.com/display-none-vs-visibility-hidden-3466884